# number of primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_9$

Tags: finite-fields

How can we find number of primitive elements in the field $\mathbb{F}_9$.

$\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+1) = \mathbb{F}_9$ and  $α^4=1$. I could not improve the solution. I missunderstand the conception.
can you help me.

thanks.

Comment: Do you know group theory in general?

Comment: i know but i cant compare in finite fields. i do not know how to think. if i think simply i get no primitive elements in F9 because every element has order less than 8 which contradicts with the ord(primitive element)

Comment: What is you $a$? And you did not really answer my question about group theory? Do you know basic group theory (cyclic group and such?)

Comment: α is root. i answered. i said i knew.

Comment: What do you mean you can't compare in finite fields? You are asked about the number of generators of the multiplicative group of the field, which is a cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: original question is number of primitive elements in F9(Field). those are just my predictions about solution.

Comment: By the calculation in your previous question, $\varphi(8)$.

Comment: what is generalization of this. can we do this for all numbers or except prime. for instance F25 and F32.. because i know for F19 we have {2,3,10,13,14,15} for primitive elements.

Comment: One primitive element is $1+\alpha$. There are three more.

Comment: No point in checking the elements of the subfield $\Bbb{F}_3$. As you observed $\alpha$ has order four. That leaves elements of the form $a+b\alpha$ with $a,b$ both non-zero. Have you checked the order of the element $1+\alpha$ suggested by Derek Holt?

Comment: 1+α is primitive because the order of 1+α is 8. (1+α)^4=2. then 2^2=1.
F9={0,1,2,α,α+1,α+2,2α,2α+1,2α+2}
number of Primitive elements: φ(9-1)=φ(8)=2.(3-1)=4
So, I checked one by one. that has order 8.
Primitive elements are: {α+1,α+2,2α+1,2α+2}
is that right? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Correct. Why don't you write that as an answer!? You get some upvotes, comments, and improve the site hygiene by removing your question from the unanswered queue :-)

Comment: i am new in here and i newly get that if i do this, it is beneficial for humanity =) 
thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F9={0,1,2,α,α+1,α+2,2α,2α+1,2α+2}

Number of Primitive elements: φ(9-1)=φ(8)=2.(3-1)=4

So, I checked one by one. that has order 8.

Primitive elements are: {α+1,α+2,2α+1,2α+2}

{example: 1+α is primitive because the order of 1+α is 8. (1+α)^4=2. then 2^2=1.}

solved by Assoc.Prof @Jyrki Lahtonen and other mathematician 's helps and comments.